# Android Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForProductionDebug'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, react-native

When I run my app via Android studio everything works fine (it installs on the emulator without any worry). However when I use my CI (buddybuild), it fails with the following error message: (Command which was run: `gradle --no-daemon ":app:assemble"`)

```
:app:compileProductionDebugJavaWithJavac
:app:compileProductionDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
:app:compileProductionDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileProductionDebugSources
:app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForProductionDebug FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForProductionDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcpp.class
BUILD FAILED
Total time: 42.054 secs
```

I've setup 2 product flavors (staging & production) & I have a feeling the setup to these might be causing this issue?

Here is my build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app"
        // react-native supports >= 16
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    productFlavors {
        staging {
//            applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
            applicationId "com.app.staging"
            resValue "string", "authority", "com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider<ID_HERE>"
        }
        production {
//            applicationIdSuffix ".production"
            applicationId "com.app.production"
            resValue "string", "authority", "com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider<ID_HERE>"
        }
    }


    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk true  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile project(':gl-react-native')
    compile project(':react-native-branch')
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    compile project(':react-native-action-sheet')
    compile project(':react-native-maps')
    compile project(':react-native-fs')
    compile project(':react-native-open-settings')
    compile project(':react-native-keychain')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4+'
    compile project(':react-native-push-notification')
    compile project(':react-native-mixpanel')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile project(':react-native-extra-dimensions-android')
}
```

Here is my AndroidManifest (note: the rest of the manifest is default):

```
<provider
   android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
   android:authorities="@string/authority"
   android:exported="true" />
```

Is there any other information that would be helpful? Let me know.

NOTE: If I run ./gradlew clean, if won't change any files.

Answer (score 0):

Try excluding

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4+'

    compile project(':gl-react-native') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services'
    }
    ...

    compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services'
    }
    compile ('com.facebook.react:react-native:+') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services'
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this - It didn't work. However removing `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4+'` completely fixed the build (but i cannot open the installed app, I think removing this line made it crash).

Comment: Nope that didn't seem to fix it either :\

Comment: Hi there - Have you tried upgrading your GMS dependency to 11.4.2?